# Spring Data Jpa(JPQL) inner queries support

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have written native sql query with spring data jpa.
Now i want to convert it to the jpql query with spring data jpa only.

My Query is

```
  SELECT sample.api_name,
   sample.hitcount,
   r.unit_rate*sample.hitcount AS amnt
  FROM
  (SELECT u.api_name AS api_name,
      u.tenant_id,
      u.count AS hitcount
  FROM tableA u
   WHERE u.tenant_id = :tenant
    AND u.time_stamp BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo
    GROUP BY u.api_name,
        u.tenant_id) AS sample
     LEFT JOIN tableB r ON sample.api_name = r.api_name
     AND sample.tenant_id =r.tenant_id.
```

By seeing some reference documents i came to know that the support of inner queries in jpql is only for WHERE and HAVING clauses.

If it is a correct statement how can i convert it to JPQL query.

Please provide a solution ?

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to answer your question if you can provide schema for the tables involved along with the output you want to achieve.

Comment: Its possible to write innerquery for my above scenario.

Comment: That's the issue. Unless you give me the schema with some sample data & the output you want, i won't be able to get what is the scenario here.