# NativeSql query into JPQL query convertion

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql, criteria-api, native-sql

I have native query like this

```
  SELECT sample.api_name,
  sample.hitcount,
  r.unit_rate*sample.hitcount AS amnt
  FROM

  (SELECT u.api_name AS api_name,u.tenant_id,
     u.count AS hitcount
     FROM tableA u
     WHERE u.tenant_id = :tenant
     AND u.time_stamp BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo
     GROUP BY u.api_name,
     u.tenant_id) AS sample

  LEFT JOIN tableB r ON sample.api_name = r.api_name
  AND sample.tenant_id =r.tenant_id
```

The values "tenant,dateFrom,dateTo" values are providing by using @Param tag.

I have tried to convert to the jpql query in spring data jpa.
But by seeing in some reference documents i came to know that the
Jpql inner queries are not supported in the FROM clause.

is that my point correct or not. If not Please help me to write in JPQL if my point is correct please help to write in Criteria api.

Comment: Why does this have to be converted to JPQL? It works perfectly well in SQL, and will not be easy to emulate in JPQL. What advantage will you get out of it?

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/q/54590986/521799?